# Maximum value of function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I was exercising calculus when I stumbled upon this question:

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $$f(x)=\frac {\ln x}{x}$$
>
> What is the absolute maximum value of $f$?
>
> 1. $1$
> 2. $\cfrac1e$
> 3. $0$
> 4. $-e$
> 5. $f$ does not have an absolute maximum value

In this section I was not supposed to use a calculator so I couldn't have solved for critical points as

$$f'(x) =  \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$

So if you could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you solve for the zeros of the derivative $f'$ without a calculator?

Comment: The exercise states we cannot use calculators in this section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly found the derivative to be:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}$$
To find local extrema, let $f'(x)=0$.
$$\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}=0$$
If we multiply both sides by $x^2$, we reduce the problem to:
$$1-\ln(x)=0$$
Can you continue?

---

You can verify that your point is a maximum at a point $(c,f(c))$ by checking if $f''(c)<0$. You can also verify that this point is not only a local maximum, but also an absolute maximum.

Comment: Hint: this entire question can be solved *without* a calculator, and perhaps better be...

Comment: Oh, I see now. The answer is going to be 1/e. Thank you for clearing it up for me!

Comment: @AbuBakr You're welcome. Yes, that is correct.